# Memcache get() failure

Tags: php, memcached

I am facing some issues with memcached under heavy load.

I am using ab to stress test my site. I use one instance of memcached to store php sessions
and another one to store objects.

While benchmarking the site, I often get exceptions from the site which have to do with failing get() from memcache.

The key definitely exists in memcached.

I have configured max connections to 4096 and I run ab as

```
ab -c 200 -t 60
```

I am using php-memcache-2.2.6 client library.

Also I am monitoring memcached during the test and the

```
curr_connections variable never goes higher than 250
```

Additionally, listen_disabled_num is 0

What could be causing such failures?

Thanks

Comment: is memcached running on the same machine you're testing?

Comment: check the getExtendedStats - http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.getextendedstats.php , this should give some information

Comment: @stillstanding: I am running the benchmark from another machine in the same network and yes memcached is on the same machine as the web app

Comment: @ajreal: The function you mentioned is the same as issuing stats to memcached through telnet. I have posted above some of the variables. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas - How is the memory size, average read per seconds (total read/uptime), evictions, missed rate ?

Comment: memory 512mb  cmd_get 128255 get_hits 128246 get_misses 9. That is strange though as I would expect the get_misses to be much more

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that iptables was the culprit of all my problems.

It was blocking requests when the number was increasing

Stopping the damned thing solved all my problems.

Hope it will help someone in the future